# mysql in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table name `\tbl_report\` and it has very large number of fields in it. Now `\tbl_report\` is not showing the fields in phpmyadmin. What could be causing this problem? Is it because of the large field that I have placed in the table?

Comment: "it has very large no.of fields" -> I suggest to normalize/optimalize it. It will help not only with display in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 3):

Is this database available in localhost, if so please install sqllyog and check if you are able to view the fields, sometime if database table has a problem such issues may occur. In sqlyog under tools menu there is a sub menu called table diagnostics, you can check your table status using it.

Comment: i have found the fields in navicat premium but i also want these fields to view from phpmyadmin what to do for that.

Comment: Could you please check , if your table is okay using navicat ?